# When did telescopes become affordable?

Tags: technology, telescope

There must have been a moment when most people had heard of telescopes, but they were only affordable by rich people or ship's captains. When did they first become affordable by the general public?

After a few hours of research, I have not found an answer to this online.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is meant by "general population" here?  Ship's captains were, as you note, not exactly wealthy,

Comment: The article [How Amateur Telescope Tech Unveils the Night Sky](https://www.space.com/30995-amateur-telescope-tech-history-evolution.html) suggests that the first mass-produced telescope available to amateurs was developed in the 1960s as the Schmidt-Cassegrains produced by Celestron.  I imagine it was still rather pricey.

Comment: So far there are two answers to a similar queston: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39100/when-did-telescopes-become-available(https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/39100/when-did-telescopes-become-available)

Comment: I remember reading about grinding one's own lens for the refractor when I was a kid (in the '60s), it just needs glass and patience. The old astronomers used aerial telescopes, Hevelius had a very large one in Gdansk.